# How to disable background when keyboard appears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I want to disable the application background when the UITextField keyboard appears. I would like to create the same effect of the Action Sheet. Is it possible?
Thanks, Luigi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add a clear (or tinted) view that covers the entire view controller's view. This would appear under the keyboard so you would still be able to type. But the view would prevent any touch interactions with the rest of the view controller (including the text field).

You could implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` so it adds the view and the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method so it removes the view.

Of course you need to ensure that the keyboard input allows you to dismiss the keyboard, otherwise the view will never get removed.

BTW - why do you want to do this? It's very unusual.

Comment: I would say this option is best... (he wants an actionsheet like view : as he said :))